# List Views not showing certain field data for Infopath Form Library 2010

Tags: 2010, infopath, list-view

Has anyone ever had the problem where a SharePoint 2010 InfoPath Form Library will randomly 'disconnect' itself from certain fields from the form data in the list view?

Hard to explain I guess. But, it seems that some of the fields from the form data are not showing up on any view we create or pull up. There doesn't seem to be a pattern either, just very random. Some of the newer records show the field data in the views, while others don't, and the same goes for some of the older data. When you pull up the form, the data is there, it's just not showing in the views.

What may be causing the views to not see the field data for some records but see it for others? Any and all help is appreciated!

*Edit:* I was able to re-link a few of the form's with the library and the data re-appears. Unfortunately, it also updates the 'Last Modified' date and states that I was the last person to modify the record. Is there any way to re-link the data without modifying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've at least gotten part of a fix. This is a problem with InfoPath publishing to form libraries: InfoPath needs to be explicitly told how to map data from your form into fields in the SharePoint library (which is done automatically for SharePoint lists). In some cases it'll do that by default to fields you've added, but in scenarios that I haven't been able to pin down it'll lose or misconfigure that mapping. You can see the settings through the Publishing Wizard or Form Options -> Property Promotion. Sorry to say that you won't be able to easily pull the data from InfoPath into the SharePoint library item properties without just opening the InfoPath form and re-saving it; you'd have to make a script to parse the xml data of the infopath form, then update the list item with [SystemUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Aron. After the users saw what happens when we relink the forms, they seemed satisfied with it enough that they are willing to ignore the issue of the modification date and user being updated. If the issue continues to arise, I'll dig into what I can do with script.